# Como debugar uma query MySQL?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, wordpress, query

Tem alguma forma de saber o que tem de errado nessa QUERY?

Quando você realiza uma query, exibe ela na tela mas não aparece nada, o `var_dump` retorna `NULL`, quais passos um profissional realiza para saber o que esta havendo de errado em uma consulta? (sou novato em back end)

```
$query = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT display_name, post_title, name

FROM $wpdb->terms 

INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = $wpdb->terms.term_id 

INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON $wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id

INNER JOIN $wpdb->posts ON $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'noo_resume' 

INNER JOIN $wpdb->users ON $wpdb->users.ID = $wpdb->posts.post_author 

INNER JOIN $wpdb->usermeta ON $wpdb->usermeta.user_id = $wpdb->users.ID AND $wpdb->usermeta.meta_key = '_jm_candidate_field_clocknow_user_btn' AND $wpdb->usermeta.meta_value = 'value_2';" );

foreach ($query as $vaga) {                 
  echo 'Nome: ' .$vaga->display_name. '<br>';
  echo 'Currículo: ' .$vaga->post_title. '<br>';
  echo 'Cargo: ' .$vaga->name. '<br>';
  echo '<hr>';
}
```

Modelo Relacional da Tabela

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Comment: Olha a última linha, `meta_key` e `meta_value` pretencem a qual tabela? Você usa phpMyAdmin ou similares?

Comment: Oi Rodrigo, eu começaria investigando a própria database do WordPress, da tabela mais interna para a mais externa... Veja se existem entradas em `wp_usermeta` onde `meta_key = '_jm_candidate_field_clocknow_user_btn' AND meta_value = 'value_2'` (se for isso mesmo que você quer). Depois faça o join para `users` e veja se você consegue retornar os ids dos usuários... Então faça o join com posts, etc, até você ter tudo o que precisa.

Comment: Thiago, arrumei a query... `meta_key` e `meta_value` pertencem a tabela `wp_usermeta` ($wpdb->usermeta). Mas mesmo assim ainda continua com o mesmo problema.

Comment: Anthony, sim tem entradas no wp_usermeta e meta_key com esses valores. Olha, eu até consigo retornar todos os dados, mas para a consulta ser certa mesmo tem que haver essas 2 condições `$wpdb->usermeta.meta_key = '_jm_candidate_field_clocknow_user_btn' AND $wpdb->usermeta.meta_value = 'value_2'`. Por mais simples que parece eu não estou conseguindo implementar isso na consulta.

Comment: Então, todas a questão é se os joins estão corretos e se há dados que ligam todas as tabelas. Por isso que o plano é testar um join por vez. Comece com `SELECT * FROM $wpdb->usermeta WHERE  $wpdb->usermeta.meta_key = '_jm_candidate_field_clocknow_user_btn' AND $wpdb->usermeta.meta_value = 'value_2';` e vá construindo daí.